# NoMethodError - undefined method `timestamp_sort_order' for Paper trail issue after upgrading Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, paper-trail-gem

I used paper_trail to tracking transnational changes when I migrated rails 3.2 to rails 4.2, have got below issue:

> NoMethodError - undefined method `timestamp_sort_order' for

Answer (score 8):

got this on rails 6.0.0beta3 because I patched papertrail and forgot to add `PaperTrail::VersionConcern`, e.g.:

```rb
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
  end
end
```

---

`PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!` did not fix it for me

looking at the [source code](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/model_config.rb#L213-L215) it's calling it directly on an `ActiveRecord::Base` model, it's defined on `PaperTrail::VersionConcern`.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by adding below line in intializer paper_trail.rb file

```
PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!
```

See my final intializers/paper_trail.rb file

```
PaperTrail.config.track_associations = false

PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!

module PaperTrail

  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    .....
  end

end
```

Problem resolved....

Have updated my answer added  below line extra using it with rails 5.2

```
PaperTrail.config.track_associations = false
```

Comment: hi, this solution didn't work for me.   i copied the exact paper_trail.rb file   I'm using ruby '2.1.2', gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

Comment: Please check your paper_trail version, I used with paper_trail 4.0.0. may be you used with latest try to use paper_trail 4.0.0 hope that should work.

Comment: hi rameshwar, i was able to fix it. what I did wrong was instead of creating a paper trail initializer i created a model for it.

Comment: hi rameshwar, this solution only works if I declare the module PaperTrail inside the initializer config. But if I create the module PaperTrail inside app/models/paper_trail/version, it fails.

Comment: hi @rameshwar, can you help me out on this ?   https://gist.github.com/sbpipb/502a5ff7848991f2e4c7

Comment: I replied github URL, please check.

Comment: @RameshwarVyevhare This Solution is not working for me.. I am using  paper_trail (10.2.1), My model in which i need paper_trail enable contains `  has_paper_trail versions: { class_name: "PimHistory" }, ignore: [:updated_at]
`

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6, the preferred method is now to create a model, do not put model code in the initializer. This is what I'm using...

```
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    include PaperTrail::VersionConcern

    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
  end
end
```