# Upgrading to papertrail 4.0 (undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for PaperTrail::Version:Class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I have upgraded my rails app to use papertrail 4.0-stable version.
But i am getting 
**undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for PaperTrail::Version:Class**

Gem versions: papertrail-4.0-stable, rails-4.2.4

Comment: Do you have the same issue with `4.0.0`? What is the smallest amount of code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: In lieu of a reproduction, do you at least have a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Add `PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!` to an initializer.

Found on:
[NoMethodError - undefined method `timestamp_sort_order' for Paper trail issue after upgrading Rails 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716983/nomethoderror-undefined-method-timestamp-sort-order-for-paper-trail-issue-af)