# Papertrail 10.2.1 undefined method `timestamp_sort_order' for Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I am using paper_trail (https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) in My Rails 5.2.1 and Ruby 2.5.1. My Model and controller Contains Following code

```
class ModelName < ApplicationRecord    
   has_paper_trail versions: { class_name: "History" }, ignore:  [:updated_at] 
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_paper_trail_whodunnit
   def current_user
     if !(@current_user)
       @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
    end
    return @current_user
  end
end
```

When I am trying to save record of particular model it gives

```
 undefined method `timestamp_sort_order' for <Class>
```

I have tried this solution [NoMethodError - undefined method `timestamp_sort_order' for Paper trail issue after upgrading Rails 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716983/nomethoderror-undefined-method-timestamp-sort-order-for-paper-trail-issue-af) 
but still it is not working.

I inspected the paper trail gem and found that this method is class level method and it is not available in my `History` Model.

PS: I am using authlogic (https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I got caught by this as well upgrading to rails-6.0.  Finally found this in the docs which fixed it:

> If you only use custom version classes and don't have a versions table, 
>   you must let ActiveRecord know that the PaperTrail::Version class is an
>   abstract_class.

```
# app/models/paper_trail/version.rb
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
    self.abstract_class = true
  end
end
```